# How to implement cumulative sum for specific group in informatica

Tags: transformation, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have below data set

```
ESN | DATE   | SV_NO
123 | 22-NOV | 2
123 | 23-NOV | 2
123 | 25-NOV | 3
123 | 27-NOV | 2
123 | 27-NOV | 3
123 | 28-NOV | 4
123 | 28-NOV | 2
124 | 21-NOV | 0
124 | 23-NOV | 3
124 | 24-NOV | 3
124 | 25-NOV | 2
124 | 27-NOV | 2
124 | 28-NOV | 3
124 | 30-NOV | 0
```

and I want to achieve below output using [informatica](/questions/tagged/informatica). All data is sorted based on `ESN` and `DATE`. I have to calculate the `SUM` on the basis of `ESN` and `SV_NO` 0.11 value is stored in one variable port.

```
ESN | DATE   | SV_NO | SUM
123 | 22-NOV | 2     | 0.11
123 | 23-NOV | 2     | 0.22
123 | 25-NOV | 3     | 0.11
123 | 27-NOV | 2     | 0.33
123 | 27-NOV | 3     | 0.22
123 | 28-NOV | 4     | 0.11
123 | 28-NOV | 2     | 0.44
124 | 21-NOV | 0     | 0.11
124 | 23-NOV | 3     | 0.11
124 | 24-NOV | 3     | 0.22
124 | 25-NOV | 2     | 0.11
124 | 27-NOV | 2     | 0.22
124 | 28-NOV | 3     | 0.33
124 | 30-NOV | 0     | 0.22
```

Please provide me the proper solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the data by ESN and SV_NO. Then in an Expression transformation, do the following:

```
ESN: <-- I/O port
DATE: <-- I/O port
SV_NO: <-- I/O port
v_CONST:=0.11
v_SUM:= IIF(ESN = v_prev_ESN AND SV_NO=v_prev_SV_NO, v_SUM+v_CONST, v_CONST)
o_SUM:= <-- Output port
v_prev_ESN:= ESN
v_prev_SV_NO:= SV_NO
```

Now, again sort the data by ESN and DATE before loading the target